# Selenium server did not start.Another Selenium process may already be running or your java version may be out of date

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, polymer, polymer-cli

Just starting out with Polymer and Unit Testing. I was trying out the activity on this page https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/tests but I couldn't get `polymer test` to run. So I tried running `polymer test --verbose` and end up getting this error:

`Error: Selenium server did not start.Another Selenium process may already be running or your java version may be out of date.`

error:   cli runtime exception: Error: Selenium server did not start.Another Selenium process may already be running or your java version may be out of date.
error:   Error: Selenium server did not start.Another Selenium process may already be running or your java version may be out of date.
    at ChildProcess.errorIfNeverStarted (C:\Users\Eleonor Somosot\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\selenium-standalone\lib\start.js:141:15)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)

Hoping someone could help me with this and maybe explain. Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hit below url for shut down already running selenium server on port 4444.

http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer

If selenium server is already running on port 4444 then it will shut down the server and says OK if selenium is not running on this port 4444 then by hitting above url will give you "Unable to connect"

If no server was running, Tuned out the java version was in cause. Make sure you are running java 7 or higher:

```
java -version
```

Comment: hi thank you for the response. it seems that selenium server is not running. im working on a windows 10 machine. i tried polymer test command again and it is still on "Installing and starting Selenium server for local browsers" it printed after couple of minutes. is selenium really slow? or does it have drawbacks in windows?

Comment: update, i run polymer test command again because i accidentally ended the previous one. and it does not progress to anything now.

Comment: @EleonorSomosot  If no server was running, Tuned out the java version was in cause. Make sure you are running java 7 or higher:

`java -version`

Comment: Hey! turns out you were right. The problem was with my outdated java version. I was running v7 and tried updating it to latest v8. I thought I always had the latest.THANKS!